# What is the difference between "important for" and "important in"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

> - The Independent: maintaining independence is **important in** relationships.
> - The Telegraph: Protein intake is also very **important in** building muscle.
> - BBC: Meals are also **important for** building business relationships.
> - The Guardian: Personalised content is increasingly **important for** building brand relationships.
> - The Guardian: She says the course is especially **important for** building the confidence of teenagers who lack support at home.

**I think there is a difference in meaning between "important in" and "important for", but I don't know what it is.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of **important** is the same in all of these sentences. The choice of **in** vs. **for** is governed by the words that follow. The examples with **in** use that preposition in the sense of "part of" or "an ingredient of", and the examples with **for** use it in the sense of "in order to", i.e. to say that something is a prerequisite for another thing.

You could rewrite these sentences like:

> Maintaining independence is **an important ingredient of**/**plays an important role in** relationships.
>
> Protein intake is also very **important as part of** building muscle.
>
> Personalised content is increasingly important **in order to build** brand relationships.
>
> > or, Personalised content is **an increasingly important prerequisite for** building brand relationships.

In some of these examples, both **in** and **for** would work - for example, protein intake is an important part of building muscle, but it's also a prerequisite for building muscle, so you could say "**in** building muscle" and "**for** building muscle".